# Parse ZonedDateTime from String containing milliseconds

Tags: java, java-8, date

I need to get ZonedDateTime from the String of the following format:

```
"26.06.2019T00:00:00.123+03:00"
```

This format seems to be a standard one, so I used the following code to parse ZonedDateTime from the string:

```
ZonedDateTime.parse("26.06.2019T00:00:00.123+03:00");
```

However, I get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '26.06.2019T00:00:00.123+03:00' could not be parsed at index 0
```

Comment: javaDoc: Obtains an instance of `ZonedDateTime` from a text string such as `2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00[Europe/Paris]`

Comment: The default formatter is `ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME`, see its format here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME .

Comment: "This format seems to be a standard one" -> nope. It looks a lot like the ISO formats, but it messes the order of the date fields. Year should be first, then month then day. Basically bigger to smaller. Also ISO uses a dash - rather than a dot . to separate date fields.

Comment: You need to change the format of the date to `2019-06-26T00:00:00.123+03:00` (*year-month-day*) or use a custom `DateTimeFormatter` since there is no default one that accepts the format *day.month.year*.

Comment: It's almost but not quite the standard ISO-8601 format. Where are you getting strings in this format from? Tell the people who give you these strings to use the actual ISO-8601 format (with `yyyy-MM-dd` instead of `dd.MM.yyyy`) instead of such a strange and confusing almost-but-not-really-standard format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format you are using is not a standard format since you are using `dd.mm.yyyy` for the date instead of `yyyy-mm-dd`. Therefore it does not work with the default formatter used by `parse()`.

You can easily set up a custom `DateTimeFormatter` for your special case:

```
String pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX";
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);

String input = "26.06.2019T00:00:00.123+03:00";
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(input, dtf);
```

---

The output of `System.out.println(zonedDateTime)` is then the correct ISO-format:

```
2019-06-26T00:00:00.123+03:00
```

As per [Jesper's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56699086/parse-zoneddatetime-from-string-containing-milliseconds/56699413#comment99963066_56699086), I would advise you to use the actual standard format and to try to convince whoever is supplying you those string to use the actual ISO format as well.